# How to get particular data from the Openstruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, garb-gem

I am using garb gem to fetch the data from the google analytics and I getting the data in Openstruct format and I am struggling to parse it and get the desired values out.

```
#<OpenStruct visits="142640", percent_new_visits="100.0", visitor_type="New Visitor">
```

I googled but did not find anything relevant to this. I am newbie to ruby on rails ENV.

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just call method on args like

```
object.visits
object.percent_new_visits
object.visitor_type
```

See the document about OpenStruct on Ruby doc http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/index.html